# can someone help me start my node please

Tags: nodes

Using raspberry pi model 3 which is running raspbian, a flavor of debian.

I had the full wallet installed and syncing the blockchain.

Now i can't remember how to get the gui up and running again.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command 'bitcoin-qt' in your terminal.

Comment: bash: bitcoin-qt: command not found

Comment: 'bitcoind' if that does work than you probably have not installed bitcoin correctly